# Converting Angular Materials to TypeScript

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angularjs-material

I am just learning AngularJS and I have followed the tutorials that use primarily TypeScript. I now want to use Angular Materials in my app and the component I need is written in JS.

From https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/slider#vertical

```
angular.module('sliderDemo2', ['ngMaterial'])

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.vol = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
  $scope.bass = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
  $scope.master = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
});
```

What does this look like converted to TypeScript?

Comment: Are you learning Angular (2 or 4) or AngularJs? If tutorials use TypeScript chances are its Angular (without JS sufix) so version is 2 or 4

Comment: Hi. I am learning Angular 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are learning Angular (not AngularJS) simply use Angular Materials for Angular 2/4 and it will be written in typescript:
https://material.angular.io/components/slider/overview